How to get rid off the word "Characteristic" at the beggining of the table created from gtsummary package?
I am having trouble resolving an issue with the gtsummary R package, specifically with a word that keeps appearing in the output ("Characteristic"), and I cannot figure out how to remove or modify it. The word seems to be automatically generated by the package when formatting or calculating certain statistics, such as confidence intervals, but I am unsure how to address it effectively.
Despite consulting the formal documentation for the gtsummary package, I couldn’t find a clear answer or solution to this issue. The documentation provides details on customizing tables, adding statistics, and formatting outputs, but it doesn’t seem to address this specific problem. Even when using functions like modify_header(), add_stat_label(), or add_ci(), the word still appears in the table, making it challenging to finalize a clean and professional result. I’ve tried various approaches, including adjusting the statistic argument and modifying table formatting with tbl_svysummary() and tbl_summary(), but the issue persists.

trial |> tbl_summary() |> modify_header(label = "")
